# "Killing" or "Killings"?

Tags: grammar

I need help with the title for a paper I'm writing. The paper is about two individuals who were killed, potentially by mistake, by the US government. The two people in question were siblings, but were killed years apart. So should the title be "The US Killing of John and Jane Doe" or "The US Killings of John and Jane Doe"?

Comment: They are both grammatical. It depends on if you are referring to the *general concept* or to the *specific incidents*. There can be ***a*** *drug problem* and instances of *problems with drugs*.

Comment: The explanation above sounds right but as a reader, I felt naturally inclined to the second title - "The US Killings of John and Jane Doe". Therefore, I would suggest that you chose your title based on what you find most natural (perhaps, you can request input from your peers) since both are grammatically correct.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful responses. So “killings” would refer to a general concept? I guess that would mean I should go with “killing,” since I’m talking about two specific incidents.